# Cavalieri's Principle in measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, lebesgue-measure

The first part of Cavalieri's principle (in measure theory) states if $E$ is measurable, then almost every slice $E_x$ of $E$ is measurable.

Here, it uses "almost every", so what is an example where not all slices of E is measurable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you take a set of the form $\{0\} \times A$, where $A$ is non-measurable?  This is measurable of measure zero, being a subset of the the measure zero set $\{0\} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So you mean we take slice on the first coordinate ({0}), we get A if x=0, which is not measurable, but when x is not 0, we get empty, which is measurable?

Comment: @naga If you would prefer the slices to be nonempty for some reason you could take $\{0\} \times A \cup \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$.  The slice at $x=0$, $A \cup \{0\}$ will still be non-measurable, and the other slices will be the measurable set $\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks very much! The slice can definitely be empty, and I am just saying that to make sure I understand your point.